# mysqli query returns false

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to run a select query on my db via php mysqli but, it keeps returning false. I know it's not query syntax since I got it straight from phpMyAdmin and there it actually returns a row.

Here's my php:

```
    //connect
$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$dbname);

//test connection
if(!$conn){
    die("Connection Failed:"." ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$VendorID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['vendorID']);
$VendorPass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['vendorPass']);

$query = $sql = "SELECT * FROM `zobo_vendors` WHERE vendorID = \'L00001\' LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

print(mysqli_num_rows($result));

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if($VendorPass == $row['vendorPass']){
        date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Johannesburg");
        $day = date("d");
        $monthNum  = date("m");
        $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
        $monthName = $dateObj->format('M');

        $date = $day." ".$monthName.", ".date("h:i");
        echo "<script>window.AppInventor.setWebViewString('CorrectPass');</script>";
        echo $date;
    }else{
        echo "<script>window.AppInventor.setWebViewString('WrongPass');</script>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<script>window.AppInventor.setWebViewString('NonExist');</script>";
}

if($result === FALSE) {
die("Uh oh something went wrong");
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Here's the same query via phpmyAdmin

[image: The query via phpMyAdmin]

Comment: You should learn to check `mysqli_error($conn)` to find out why the query failed. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get MySQLi error information in different environments? / mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli\_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments-mysqli-fetch-as)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it *is* your query syntax.
You took a query straight from phpmyadmin *that would have worked if you put it inside **single** quotes* - but you put it inside **double** quotes.

Instead of:

> "SELECT * FROM `zobo_vendors` WHERE vendorID = \'L00001\' LIMIT 0, 30 "

Do:

> 'SELECT * FROM `zobo_vendors` WHERE vendorID = \'L00001\' LIMIT 0, 30 '

The first one doesn't work because **in a double-quoted string, single-quote does not need escaping.** Because of this, the backslash character does not get removed.

In phpmyadmin, the text of query was this:

> SELECT * FROM `zobo_vendors` WHERE vendorID = 'L00001' LIMIT 0, 30

Your query text literally is this:

> SELECT * FROM `zobo_vendors` WHERE vendorID = \'L00001\' LIMIT 0, 30

It goes to MySQL with backslashes in it!

---

Alternatively, you could have removed the backslashes:

> "SELECT * FROM `zobo_vendors` WHERE vendorID = 'L00001' LIMIT 0, 30 "

---

ABS Rana's answer is another valid alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you can use double quotation instead of single quotation

```
$query = $sql = "SELECT * FROM `zobo_vendors` WHERE vendorID = \"L00001\" LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```